# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject me retorna algunos valores en NULL

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

Estoy trabajando con un archivo en JSON que viene con una estructura específica, la cual al momento de hacer el proceso de deserialización me retorna algunos de los valores en null.

El archivo origen que estoy procesando es el siguiente:

```
{
"t":"i",
"v":
[
    {
        "id":604618,
        "url":"http://wsplus.navego360.com/images/services/215/37480914/604618.jpg",
        "last_log":
        {
            "t":"n",
            "dt":"2018-08-16T19:03:47.962Z",
            "c_lat":-12.014695,
            "c_lon":-76.93001
        }
    },
    {
        "id":604619,
        "url":"http://wsplus.navego360.com/images/services/215/37480914/604619.jpg",
        "last_log":
        {
            "t":"n",
            "dt":"2018-08-16T19:03:55.667Z",
            "c_lat":-12.014695,
            "c_lon":-76.93001
        }
    }
],
"st":"p"
}
```

Este archivo puede retornar varios URL con diferentes fotos, las cuales debo poder recuperar, sin importar si solo es un URL o varios.

La estructura en C# que va a recibir los valores es la siguiente:

```
public class ListaFotos
{
    public string t { get; set; }
    public List<FotoURL> fotos { get; set; }
    public string st { get; set; }
}

public class FotoURL
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> last_log { get; set; }
}
```

Para hacer la conversión hacia C# estoy utilizando la siguiente línea de código:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DatosRetorno.ListaFotos>(jsonFotos);
```

Los valores que no estoy recibiendo son los que están dentro de la lista `List<FotoURL>`, que corresponde con la sección "v" del archivo JSON, que es justamente la parte más importante, ya que ahí se encuentran las imagenes que debo recuperar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es muy importante tener en cuenta que las herramientas que descerealizan JSON, necesitan las clases donde van a dejar los datos del mismo. Y para llenar los valores de esas clases, utilizan los valores que aparecen en el JSON.

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` utiliza la clase que le pasaste, para transformar los datos del JSON a esa clase. Y para eso, por `reflection`, busca los nombres de las propiedades de la clase que coinciden con los datos del JSON.

En este caso, sabe que tu json tiene como datos a nivel cabecera (por poner un nombre) a los elementos `t`, `v` y `st`. Entonces necesita que la clase, tenga esas propiedades para saber donde bajar esos datos.

Sin embargo, tu clase esta construida asi:

```
public class ListaFotos
{
    public string t { get; set; }
    public List<FotoURL> fotos { get; set; }
    public string st { get; set; }
}
```

En la cual vemos a `t` y `st`, pero no encontramos a `v`, en su lugar encontramos a la lista fotos. El descerealizador, no sabe que hacer con fotos, y no sabe a donde mandar v (no, no es inteligente!) y por lo tanto, no baja los datos de v a ningun lado.

Debes cambiar el nombre en tu clase para que matchee con los nombres del json asi:

```
public class ListaFotos
{
    public string t { get; set; }
    public List<FotoURL> v{ get; set; }
    public string st { get; set; }
}
```